# Javascript Array appearing as blank in the console but contains objects in it, how to access the objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

A javascript array appearing as blank like">[]" in the console, But after exploring the blank array I am getting  array and objects in it. When trying to access the objects it throwing undefind  massege. How to solve the problem.

```
$("#select_category").keyup(function(){
    var query = $("#select_category").val();
    var allcategory = [];

    $.get('api/autocomplete/' + query).done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(data, category) {
            allcategory.push(category);
        });
        var mycategorycollection = JSON.stringify(allcategory);
        console.log(mycategorycollection);
        //Showing json data
    });

    console.log(allcategory);
    //Showing Blank array.
});
```

Here I noticed two factors;

1. When the array is placing in the .get()function's scope, then it delivering perfect data. (Please see the code)
2. When the array is placing out of the .get() function's scope then it delivering blank array.  (Please see the code )

Comment: The AJAX request in `$.get` is asynchronous which means your second `console.log()` executes before the `allcategory` array is filled. All code reliant on the AJAX request *must* be placed in the callback.

Comment: Thank you.@RoryMcCrossan